# Derivative of volume of ball is surface area of sphere, but derivative of area of square is half its perimeter.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

The derivative of the volume of a ball WRT radius is the surface area of the 2-sphere.

The derivative of the  area of a circle is WRT radius is the circumference.

And yet, the derivative of the area of a square WRT length is only half its perimeter. Why?

I have knowledge of exterior calculus- that the exterior derivative can be interpreted as the boundary of a form. I believe that the phenomena of taking derivatives to recover the boundary of the manifold has something to do with this- but I do not know why this process only recovers half the perimeter of a square.

Comment: The analogue of "radius" for a square should be "half a side length", right?  What's the derivative of the area of a square in these units?

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, if you increase the radius of a ball of radius $r$ by $dr$ the added volume is a shell with area the area of the sphere and thickness $dr$.  The new volume is $\frac 43 \pi (r+dr)^3-\frac 43\pi r^3 \approx 4\pi r^2 dr$.  Similarly if you expand a square of side $s$ by $ds$ the added area is the area between two squares.    The comparable variable to the radius for a square is half the side, so the area is $4(\frac s2)^2$.  The new area is $4(\frac s2 +d\frac s2)^2-4(\frac s2)^2\approx 4s\ d\frac s2$.  $4s$ is the perimeter of the square.

Comment: (+1 from me.  On the off chance you made this community wiki due to my comment, I don't care about reputation points, so I couldn't mind if you deleted this answer and reposted it in a non-CW form)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how big $\pi$ is.  Consider a regular $n$-gon and call the distance between its center and one of its sides its radius $r$. (In case of a square with side $a$ we have $r=a/2$.)  Now we define a discrete $\pi_n$ for every regular $n$-gon as the ratio of its circumference and its diameter.  It turns out that $\pi_n=n\cdot\tan(\pi/n)$.  (For a square we would have $4a/a=4$.)

In that case the area $A_n=\pi_n\cdot r^2$ and the circumference is $2\pi_n\cdot r$, that is the derivative of the area in respect to the radius.

Indeed, for a square we get $A_4=\pi_4\cdot r^2=4\cdot(a/2)^2=a^2$ and the circumference equals $\pi_4\cdot 2r=4\cdot2(a/2)=4a$ .